# Change a Layout to use a Imageview or 2 imageviews

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I´m a little familiarized with android development, so I will do a magazine app, with some pages using imageviews,  one requisite is the app will work in Landscape and Portrait mode, but with one diference, in Portrait will show one page, Landscape will show 2 pages. I always worked with others developers that did the layout, but this time I will do all work. The pages will change using swype method, so I think using a android view pager is an adequate method to do this: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html but I need to change between a portrait and landscape view, how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a layout to landscape mode and other to portrait. For example you activity_main.xml layout is on folder res/layout you can create a version on res/layout-land with the same name.

for more details please read: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers